# Interdependency between 2 files in an R package

Tags: r, package, r-s4

I am writing a package that contains two R files, `file1.R` and `file2.R`. The first file contains several function and S4 object definitions that the second file uses. I tried adding `source("file1.R")` to the top of `file2.R` but when I installed the library, it threw an error: `cannot open file 'rgrokit.R': No such file or directory` even though the two files are located in the same directory.

How do I make the second file dependent on the first?

Edit: If I do not try to create some form of dependency, the library installation will throw an error.

```
Error in setMethod("foo", "bar", function(.Object, ...) { : 
  no existing definition for function ‘foo’
```

This code appears in `file2.R`.

In this example, `bar` is an S4 class defined in `file1.R` and `foo` is a method which was created using `setGeneric` in `file1.R`

Comment: Because I'm curious, could you also describe what happens when you try to build the library without the `source()` command in the second file?

Comment: You don't need the explicit `source` when building a package. The build process will automatically source all your .R files; the presence of the statement is probably confusing it.

Comment: The problem here is that the build process is sourcing file2.R before file1.R. See if combining the two files into one fixes it.

Comment: If I move the `setGeneric` call to create the method to `file2.R` as well, then it will correctly install. However, I would like for all the `setGeneric` calls to be in `file1.R` for the sake of organization. I would like to create all the methods for the S4 object in `file1.R` and then define them elsewhere. I think this is somewhat analogous to defining a class in a .h file and then defining the member functions in a .cpp file for C++.

Comment: @Hong Ooi: yes, putting all the code in the one file would fix this issue. However, that file is getting rather lengthy (about 1000 lines) and I would like to split it up so it is more organized and easier to debug/edit later.

Comment: @HongOoi Can't you change the order in which they are processed using `Collate`?

Comment: As @joran mentioned using Collate to specify the order the files should be read in is the way to go here.